# Create two configurations for a grunt plug-in that is not multi-taskable

Tags: gruntjs

I use a grunt package called [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess), Obviously, it doesn't support multi-tasks.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  preprocess: {
    options: {
      context: {
        ENV: grunt.option('env') || 'prod'
      },
    },
    all_from_dir: {
      src: '*.*',
      cwd: 'src/',
      dest: 'src',
      expand: true
    }
  },
})
```

Now I want to execute `preprocess` twice, once from the `src` directory, and once from the `dist` directory. How should I configure this package to achieve that?

I have tried this configuration;

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  preprocess: {
    first: {
      options: {
        context: {
          ENV: grunt.option('env') || 'prod'
        },
      },
      all_from_dir: {
        src: '*.*',
        cwd: 'src/',
        dest: 'src',
        expand: true
      }
    },
    second: {
      options: {
        context: {
          ENV: grunt.option('env') || 'prod'
        },
      },
      all_from_dir: {
        src: '*.*',
        cwd: 'dist/',
        dest: 'dist',
        expand: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and then execute `grunt preprocess:first`. However it does not work:

> ```
> PS D:\workspace\environment-compile> grunt preprocess:first
> Running "preprocess:first" (preprocess) task
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right `preprocess` is single Task only, therefore doesn't allow multiple [targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) to be defined.

You'll need to create another custom task that dynamically configures the `preprocess` Task and then runs it.

For example:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    preprocess: {
      options: {
        context: {
          ENV: grunt.option('env') || 'prod'
        },
      },
      all_from_dir: {
        src: '*.*',
        cwd: 'src/',
        dest: 'src',
        expand: true
      }
    },
    // ...
  });

  // Custom task dynamically configures the `preprocess` Task and runs it.
  grunt.registerTask('preprocess_dist', function() {
    grunt.config.set('preprocess.all_from_dir.cwd', 'dist/');
    grunt.config.set('preprocess.all_from_dir.dest', 'dist');
    grunt.task.run(['preprocess']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('preprocessBoth', [ 'preprocess', 'preprocess_dist' ]);

};
```

**Running:**

Via your CLI run the following single command to execute the `preprocess` task twice, once from the `src` directory, once from the `dist` directory:

```
grunt preprocessBoth
```

**Explanation:**

1. The custom Task named `preprocess_dist` dynamically configures the values for the `cwd` and `dest` properties, setting them to `'dist/'` and `'dist'` respectively. This is done via the [`grunt.config.set`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.set) method
2. Then the task is run via the [`grunt.task.run`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run) method.
3. The last line of code that reads:

   ```js
   grunt.registerTask('preprocessBoth', [ 'preprocess', 'preprocess_dist' ]);
   ```

   creates a task named `preprocessBoth` and adds the following two tasks to to the [`taskList`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask):

   - `preprocess`
   - `preprocess_dist`
4. Essentially what happens when you run `grunt preprocessBoth` is:

   - The `preprocess` task runs using files from the `src` directory.
   - Then the custom `preprocess_dist` task runs using files from the `dist` directory.
5. If you prefer, you can also run each task independently via CLI, i.e:

   `grunt preprocess`

   and

   `grunt preprocess_dist`

Comment: Yes！Sorry for the late reply, I have solved this problem with your method。Thank you